# PHP redirect and load content with jQuery / AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have to create a simple website with various pages (5-6). Now I have one "master" page called index.php like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This page has also other div's on it, like a header where I show some images etc. and is styled with a css.

Now when the user clicks on a link in the menu bar, whatever page I want to show is loaded via jQuery/AJAX into the content div. I do this here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Per default load home.php
var url= "home.php";
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
           $('#content').html(data);
      }
    });         
$('#register').click(function() {
    var url= "register.php";
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
           $('#content').html(data);
      }
    });
});
// more pages here..
});
```

This works perfectly fine and I am happy with the result, now on to the problem.
On some of these pages (like register.php) I have forms that I submit. Now once I submit the form and do various things like database operations etc. I want to redirect to one of the other pages and maybe show a short information message. What I do to redirect in the php file is the following:

```
header('Location: ../app/index.php');
```

I got this somewhere from a code snippet, so I am not sure if this is the proper way to do this. Because I have per default set the index.php to load my home.php content, it always redirects to my home.php content and I was happy with this. But what if I want to redirect to another page, lets say go.php? How would I do this? Is this even possible from php or do I need to do this with javascript/jQuery?

I am a bit lost here, have tried searching for it but didn't come across exactly this issue here.

Comment: call index.php with a get variable or a session one. Then on index.php check, if is not setted the var you load home, otherwise you load the page and the (if used sessions) you unset the var.

Answer (score 1):

**For submit form and database connection :**

you can use **onclick** function to handle actions for submit button :

example in .JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var input = $('#textfiel').val();
        $.post("ajaxHandle.php",
            {data:input }
          ).success(function(responce){
              $('#responceMessage').prepend(responce);
              /* This is the field on your index.php page where you want to display msg */
          });
    });
});
```

ajaxHandle.php file:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 $inputData = $_POST['data'];

/* your database code will be done here you can find user input data in $inputData */

    echo "registration successful"; /* this string will be get in var responce in .JS file */
}
```

**To redirect page dynamically :**

you can use .load() function for example :

```
$('#content').load('../app/register.php');
```

use this http://api.jquery.com/load/ reference to use it.